# Linq except two IEnumerable queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, fluent-nhibernate, ienumerable

I have a two linq query that returns type of IEnumerable. First query returns filtered values and second query return all values I want to except from second query to first query like minus operator in SQL and bind to my listboxs.

my code sample =>

```
using (ISession session = SessionManager.CurrentSession)
        {
            IEnumerable<RoleDefinition> roleAssigned = from groupRole in session.Query<GroupRole>()
                join roleDef in session.Query<RoleDefinition>() on groupRole.RoleDefinitionId equals
                    roleDef.RoleDefinitionId
                where groupRole.GroupId == SelectedGroupId
                orderby roleDef.RoleName
                select new RoleDefinition
                {
                    RoleName = roleDef.RoleName
                };

            IEnumerable<RoleDefinition> roleUnassigned = from grole in session.Query<RoleDefinition>()
                orderby grole.RoleName
                select new RoleDefinition
                {
                    RoleName = grole.RoleName
                };

            List<RoleDefinition> lRoleAss = roleAssigned.ToList();
            List<RoleDefinition> lRoleUnAss = roleUnassigned.ToList();
            lRoleUnAss = lRoleUnAss.Where(x => !lRoleAss.Contains(x)).ToList();

            lsbAssigned.DataSource = lRoleAss;
            lsbAssigned.TextField = "RoleName";
            lsbAssigned.ValueField = "RoleName";
            lsbAssigned.DataBind();

            lsbUnAssigned.DataSource = lRoleUnAss;
            lsbUnAssigned.TextField = "RoleName";
            lsbUnAssigned.ValueField = "RoleName";
            lsbUnAssigned.DataBind();
        }
```

**EDIT =>** I fixed my code as below and my function works successfully

```
      List<RoleDefiniton> filteredUnassign = lRoleUnAss.Where(def => !lRoleAss.Select(x => x.RoleName).Contains(def.RoleName)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line:

```
lRoleUnAss = lRoleUnAss.Where(x => !lRoleAss.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

To

```
var results = lRoleUnAss.Except(lRoleAss).ToList();
```

and use `results` to get the final list.

I declared a new variable because i do not know if you want to keep the initial list intact or not. If you do not mind changing it you may try:

```
lRoleUnAss = lRoleUnAss.Except(lRoleAss).ToList();
```

Comment: I've tried except function like you wrote above but It didn't work after I've tried my line also It did't work.

Comment: Do you get any error? Keep in mind that i put the results in a `results` variable, so you need to use this in your datasource. Try my edited code.

Comment: thank you for your helps I've solved my problem and I've added true code to my question.